# Scrolltorectatindexpath will not be able to scroll to particular section?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I had an application in which i want to `scrolltoindexpath` to a particular section. I am doing like this

```
[table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:anIndex] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

[table reloadData];
```

all working fine.but here the issue is tableview always kept to the bottom .

it won't scroll up after that.it will always keeping the last cell to the bottom.not scrolling up after that.I set the constraints as (0,0,0,0).

I think i miss something here .Can anybody guide me on this?

Comment: For 'scrollToRowAtIndexPath' to work, you need to wait until the tableview subviews have been layout. After the table has been added to the view, Try calling this method after a delay of 1 sec and check if this method works

Comment: can you paste some code snippet..?

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly 2 issues here.

1)

```
[table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:anIndex] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

With animated `false`, you have to forcefully call `dispatch_get_main_queue()` even if it's running on main thread. This is supposedly an iOS bug.

2) When you are trying to scroll the tableView, it calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for the available cells. However the immediate next line is calling `reloadData` which tries to call the same dataSource method. So it might be conflicting with others. So I would recommend adding a small delay for `[table reloadData];`

Comment: my pbm is its sticking to bottom.not going up .the last cell always be at the bottom.

Comment: Did you try to remove reloadData? If it goes to the top if reloadData is not present, then you have to follow the above procedure. If not, the issue might be something else. Can you confirm this?